# Не изменяется html-страница в связке Django Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема.
Задача следующая: Необходимо, чтобы при изменении url создавался соответствующий в шаблоне.
В результате, по имеющемуся коду, при переходе по url, вместо дополнения html-шаблона, создается пустая страница с json-кодом.

Коды:
Основной шаблон IAP.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charser="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" />
    <title>IAP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app/content/IAP.css'%}" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    ...
<script src="{% static 'app\scripts\jquery-1.10.2.min.js' %}"></script>
{% block javascript %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Шаблон, который должен расширять основной - IAPMakeTable.html

```
{% extends 'app/IAP.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row" id="post-container">
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
<script>
    function test_ajax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/IAPMakeTable/',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $.each(response, function (index, i) {
                    var card = '<div class="col-md-4">' +
                        '<div class="card">' +
                        '<div class="card-body">' +
                        '<h5 class="card-title">' + i.Name + '</h5>' +
                        '<p class="card-text">' + i.Model + '</p>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
                    $('#post-container').append(card);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    test_ajax();
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

View.py:

```
def IAPMakeTable(request):
    info = Win32_ComputerSystem.objects.all()
    data = []
    for i in info:
        data.append({
            'Name': i.Name,
            'Model': i.Model,
            })
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('IAPMakeTable', views.IAPMakeTable, name='IAPMakeTable')
]
```

Есть предположение у меня, что все дело в том, что я, собственно, никак не вызываю расширяющий шаблон IAPMakeTable.html. Но как это сделать, чтобы вкупе еще и вовращались json значения- не понимаю...
Заранее спасибо!